# How to combine two rows with similar timestamps and return both

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table of bouts set up like this.

```
|------------------------|
|bouts                   |
|------------------------|
|boutID                  |
|recording_athlete       |
|boutdate (timestamp)    |
|opponent                |
|recording_athlete_points|  
|------------------------|
```

Each actual meeting between two people is recorded twice in the table, with a unique boutID and boutdate (reflecting the moment when it was actually entered, but within 5 minutes of the other) and the recording athlete of one is the opponent of the other, and visa versa. The two records are not necessarily consecutive. There are additional meetings for the two participants each day, separated by longer time intervals: we're looking for the two closest in both timestamp and ID number (assuming that these are the two that belong together).

I'm trying to SELECT records that belong together into one row (and realize and want it will be done twice) such that it will output matched rows something like this:

```
boutID|recording_athlete|boutdate|opponent|recording_athlete_points|boutID_b|boutdate_b|opponent_points
01|John|2012-05-10 20:33:04|Jane|15|04|2012-05-10 20:36:12|10
04|Jane|2012-05-10 20:36:12|John|10|01|2012-05-10 20:33:04|15
```

Here is what I have so far, and where I think I need to go, but just can't figure out what to use. Some sort of interval statement? Or do I need a totally different structure?

```
SELECT 
    A.`boutID`,
    A.`recording_athlete`,
    A.`boutDate`,
    A.`opponent`,
    A.`recording_athlete_points`,
    B.`boutID` as `boutID_b`,
    B.`boutDate` as `boutdate_b`,
    B.`recording_athlete_points`as `opponent_points`
FROM bouts A
INNER JOIN bouts B on(A.`fullName` = B.`opponent` AND ????? )
ORDER by A.`boutDate`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
...
FROM bouts A
JOIN bouts B
   on A.fullName = B.opponent 
   AND B.boutdate between subdate(A.boutdate, interval 5 minute)
                      and adddate(A.boutdate, interval 5 minute)
```

If you create an index on `boutdate`:

```
create index bouts_boutdate_index on bouts(boutdate);
```

this query will perform well

Comment: No, it's not returning things matched together correctly all of the time.